# Enabling Xinerama with Dual GT1030's Causes Ubuntu 17.10 to boot to Black

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 17.10

I have dual Geforce GT1030's, with 4 monitors. I'm attempting to enable all 4 such that I can use each of them in an extended monitor display.

I've run sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa, and selected nvidia-384.111, 390.25, and 387.34, in either event the very moment that I change:
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
from 0 to 1 and reboot, the screen boots, I get the purple screen, and then it goes black. Black like the monitors are life (I can see the cursor) but no ubuntu session or login screen.

On 384.111, I disabled Wayland entirely under the gdm3 config to see if somehow that was an issue, but it didn't seem to change anything (The nvidia driver seems it might do this by default?).

Below is my xorg.conf for possible reference:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
Screen      2  "Screen2" LeftOf "Screen0"
Screen      3  "Screen3" Above "Screen0"
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load           "dbe"
Load           "extmod"
Load           "type1"
Load           "freetype"
Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Acer S211HL"
HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor1"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Acer S211HL"
HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
Identifier     "Monitor2"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Acer S211HL"
HorizSync       0.0 - 0.0
VertRefresh     0.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
Identifier     "Monitor3"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Acer S211HL"
HorizSync       0.0 - 0.0
VertRefresh     0.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 1030"
BusID          "PCI:11:0:0"
Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 1030"
BusID          "PCI:11:0:0"
Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device2"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 1030"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device3"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 1030"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device1"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen2"
Device         "Device2"
Monitor        "Monitor2"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen3"
Device         "Device3"
Monitor        "Monitor3"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: So, if I switch to LightDM and enable Xinerama, I make it to the login screen just fine, but after entering my password it seems to just freeze (other than allowing my cursor to move freely).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately Unity/Gnome3 were struggling with the dual GT1030's when Xinerama was enabled, the extensive details as to why I'm not sure, but I seemed to get further when I switched out my greeter and display manager, so my resolution was to switch to altogether to Xubuntu, which not only resolved my problem but seemed to just work, and work beautifully.